# Check if the given structure below is a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-fields

This question is linked to [Checking if the given structure is a vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240303/checking-if-the-given-structure-is-a-vector-space/2240358#2240358) . To rephrase the question :
$$ $$Let $F$ be $\Bbb R$ and let $V$ be the set $\Bbb R^+$ of all positive real numbers.
Define the "sum" denoted by α $\oplus$ β of any two positive real numbers α
and β, and define the "product" denoted by α $\odot$ β of any positive real
number α by an arbitrary (not necessarily positive) real number β as follows:
α $\oplus$ β = αβ
and
α $\odot$ β = $β^α$

$$ $$
In one proposition I am having a bit of problem! Before stating that, let me clarify why I am posting the same question again. In that particular question, clearly the question was not understood properly hence in the answer only that was clarified. What I am having is a bit more subtle :
$$$$
$$(\alpha\oplus\beta)\odot x=\alpha \odot x\oplus\beta  \odot x,\forall \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb F,x\in V$$
$$LHS=(\alpha\oplus\beta) \odot x=x^{\alpha\beta}$$
$$RHS=\alpha \odot x\oplus\beta \odot x=x^{\alpha}x^{\beta} = x^{\alpha * \beta} $$
my question is what will be tha value of * ? will it be $\oplus$ or + ? If it is $\oplus$, I can see that both L.H.S and R.H.S will be equal and the whole structure will indeed become a vector space as I have gone through all other propositions. But I am having trouble in understanding how $\oplus$ will also follow the laws of exponentiation! The natural value should be +(our good ol' even though not defined in the question), spitted out by the law of exponentiation and as a result the whole structure won't be a vector space. Can you please point out how to think about such things?
$$$$P.S: Halmos says it is a vector space.

Comment: It should be our original +, and the structure would not be a vector space.

Comment: Yeah. In the book, linear algebra problem book by Halmos, he says it is a vector space. Also in the linked question, OP was asked to prove it , so it was assumed that it is correct. Hence got confused.

Comment: I think that, in the definition of scalar multiplication, it should be $\beta>0$ and $\alpha$ any real number.

Comment: The problem is, that you use the definition of vector addition to add elements in the ground field. If it says, the ground field is $\mathbb{R}$, it usually means that you have to use the 'normal' addition and multiplication in $\mathbb{R}$ to add and multiply numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You refer to addition in $V$ with $\oplus$ and to multiplication with a scalar with $\odot$, and $F$ is $\mathbb{R}$ with just the usual addition and multiplication which we should denote by $+$ and $\cdot$.

And that is the point you are confusing here: The axiom you are interested in is
\begin{equation*}
(\alpha + \beta) \odot x = \alpha \odot x \oplus \beta \odot x
\end{equation*}
where $+$ is just the usual $+$ from the real numbers (as on the left hand side you add elements of the ground field whereas on the right hand side, you add vectors.)

Understanding this, it is straight forward to check the axiom:
\begin{equation*}
(\alpha + \beta) \odot x = x^{\alpha + \beta} = x^\alpha \cdot x^\beta = x^\alpha \oplus x^\beta = \alpha \odot x \oplus \beta \odot x.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Yes. If you separate out the field and the abelian group and let them have their own primitive operations along with these special operations for their combination, it makes sense that it is a vector space. But from the question it is not at all clear if in the field R, he is letting us have the primitive operations or defining his own. But yes, you made a really important point.

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{R}$ will just not be a field with the operations you defined, there is a reason the vectors are just the positive real numbers. What would for example $0\odot 0$ be (completely unclear without specification). Not speaking of things like $0.5 \otimes -1$.
Generally, if somebody writes 'let our field be $\mathbb{R}$' without specifying anything else, he will always mean with the natural operations $+$ and $\cdot$.

Comment: that's right! let me accept your answer.